# About assertion in Thom isomorphism theorem

Tags: homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

On page 114 of Milnor's book

https://aareyanmanzoor.github.io/assets/books/characteristic-classes.pdf

We have the next theorem

[image]

He says that $H^i(E,E_0,\mathbb{Z}_2)=0$ for $i<n$ as a consequence of the Thom somorphism, moreover, this fact is used in the second case of the proof. My question is about taking $j<0$ in the Thom isomorphism, since the cup product is only defined for non-negative dimensions in this book and others classical references. I think that is possible to extend the cup product for negative dimensions by definning $\phi^k\smile\psi^l=0^{k+l}$ if $k<0$ or $l<0$ in the cochain level (where $C^i=0$ for $i<0$), preserving all results about cup product (including relative Künneth formula), which would justify the assertion in theorem.

Could you confirm if this way is correct? Or do I necessarily have to use the Leray-Hirsch theorem as in Hatcher's algebraic topology book?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Well, cohomology with negative index is non standard terminology. But of course you can do it, and your get the same ring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already see that generalize the cup product is unnecessary. Its possible to modify the proof and show, by using the Kûnneth formula, that $H_i(E,E_0;\mathbb{Z}_2)=0$ when $i<n$ for the trivial case $E=B\times\mathbb{R}^n$, and then use this in the other cases.